# applying bayesian stats to pre-natal screening

Tags: bayesian, disease

**Can it be that given a negative test result the probability of the disease is only 0.02% ?**

I would like to know the probability of having the disease given a negative test (screening) result. I'm unsure if the contingency table and my calculations are correct.

- prevalence of 0.1% in population; 1 in 1000 people get the disease.
- screening sensitivity 80%, 4 out of 5 sick people are detected.
- screen positive 1.45% of tests, 145 out of 10000 people have a positive test result.

|  | disease | not disease |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| + | 80 | 1370 | 1450 |
| - | 20 | 98530 | 98550 |
|  | 100 | 99900 | 100000 |

Can this be answered as follows?

P(disease | screen negative) = P(screen negative | disease) * P(disease) / P(screen negative)

P(screen negative | disease) = 0.2; since 20 out of 100 people have the disease but screen negative.

P(disease) = 0.001; prevalence in population.

P(screen negative) = 1 - P(screen positive) = 1 - 0.0145 = 0.9855

**plugging in the numbers**

P(disease | screen negative) = 0.2 * 0.001 / 0.9855 = 0.02%

Comment: Also worth noting that P(disease | screen positive) ≈ 5.52%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to envision the calculations is to convert everything to units in a population (people in this case) and work with them, for example:

1. We have 10,000 people.
2. Of them, 10 (on average) will get the disease; 8 will screen positive, and 2 will screen negative.
3. 145 people (on average) out of the 10,000 will screen positive.  Therefore, 9,855 people will screen negative.
4. 2 of these 9,855 people will actually have the disease (see step 2 above.)  Therefore, the probability that someone who screened negative has the disease is 2 / 9855 = 0.02%.

So... your calculations were correct!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the logic and the numbers seem to be correct, I am not sure about the contingency table.